# Can't I import the same library in the same folder using venv?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-venv

I like to develop using Jupyter notebooks on VScode and I just started to use Poetry. I had a tree folder like this:

```
│───code
├───project_lambda
│   │   dev.ipynb
│   │   lambda_function.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───lib
│       │   api_funcs.py
│       │   aws_funcs.py
│       │   __init__.py
│      
└───tests
└───.venv
│
│ poetry.lock
│ pypoject.toml
│ README.md
```

I realized that importing `requests` in `api_funcs.py` and in `dev.ipynb` at the same time returns an error when trying to run `dev.ipynb`. I had to remove the import from `dev.ipynb` so the import in `api_funcs.py` could be made. But after removing `__init__.py` files it worked succesfully in both files.

Is there a reason for that?